# Role Hierarchy, Sharing Settings & Team Member puzzling issue

Tags: account, sharing-rule, roles, role-hierarchy, owd

I have this Role Hierarchy (assume there is only 1 user in each role listed below)

[image: Role Hierarchy Excel visualized]

**How I've set up all the accesses:**

OWD:

Account and Contract -> **Private** for both Default Internal and External Access, Grant Access Using Hierarchies TICKED.

Account Sharing Settings :

- **Owner in Role and Subordinates: Corp 1 Head** to be shared with **Role: Corp 2 Head** (meaning Corp 2 Head can see all the Account records of Corp 1 Head and below)

User Team :

- User who has the role of Corp 1 Senior Manager (Red User) & User who has the role of Corp 3 Senior Manage (Blue user) both have the **same manager which is the user from Corp 2 Head(Green User)**. Because they have the same manager, I can see Blue User have Green & Red User under his team and Red User have Green & Red User under his team. [When I say team, I mean USER team, not Account team, not Opportunity Team]

**Problem :**

Why is Red user able to some records OWNED by Blue User whereas Blue User cannot see any records OWNED by Red User?

**Ideally, both Red & Blue user are not suppose to see each other's records.** How do I resolve these accesses so that that they cannot see each other's records?

Comment: Can you please add what is your OWD settings access for "Account" object on your question?

Comment: Ok I've added bro

Answer (score 0):

First of all, My suggestion is align your org's role hierarchy is same as your people's hierarchy. Which will avoid the unwanted sharing issues and easy to understand the sharing model.

So on here, Based on your **OWD settings** the Blue User & Red User doesn't able to view the account records each other.

But On below things generally **allow the red user can see the blue users records**,

**Individual Record sharing**, If the blue user can share the records into Red user via record sharing means it's allow to Red to seen the blue user's records [to check go to the account record sharing click "Sharing" button on that specific account record].

**Default Account Team**, Check if blue user can having the red user in member of it's default account team. [to check default account team, Go to user record >> Default Account Team settings].

Thanks.

Comment: For the 3 users, there are not in any Account Teams. Also when logged in to Red user, navigating to the Account Record.. I don't see any Sharing button on Classic

Comment: `sharing` button only visible for account owner and user in higher roles only. So can you login as Blue user and check are you able to find the `Sharing` button on the account record details page [Which is also able to view by the Red User]?